# Is a way to echo the same data in different places without multiple for eaches

Tags: php

So im grabbing data from a json APi, and using a foreach to echo it out into complex links. Lets say the data includes
-title
-link 
-image

So the first foreach would loop through the data and echo it out in a format, with the image thumbnail, and the title clickable, all wrapped in a block.

Then, somewhere else in the site, I need to work with the same data, but in different formats, and I wanted to see if I could do this without using multiple foreachs everywhere.

First I need to check if a title is available, and return either true or false, 
Then I need to list out the titles again, this time as plain text, separated by a comma, and excluding the one I already checked.

Not sure if that makes sense but the code would look something like this

```
 <?php 
 $neflix = false;
 $hulu = false;
 $amazon = false;
 foreach($sources as $source) {
      if ($source['source'] == "netflix"){$neflix = true;}
      if ($source['source'] == "hulu"){$hulu = true;}
      if ($source['source'] == "amazon"){$amazon= true;}
      echo '<a href="'.$source['link'].'" class="streaming-option">
            <img src="'. get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/assets/images/sources/78x78/".$source['source'].'".png"/>
            <strong>'. $source['display_name'] .'</strong>
           </a>';
  }
```

That's what I have so far for the first loop. I declared the initial titles outside the foreach loop so I can use them later elsewhere I the code, and then check if they exist inside of the loop, and set it to true if they do.

So I'm just wondering if I would need to set up a completely different foreach loop, if I wanted to simply list out the same titles in text format in another section, separated by comma, instead of a full link, and excluding a source in each of them (I would have to create a comma separated list for each one, the hulu and netflix and amazon in the example above)

Im thinking the second part would look like this

```
<?php
if($netflix == true) {
echo "Yes, Netflix is available, it is also available in ";
foreach($sources as $source) {
      if ($source['source'] != "netflix") {
      echo $source['display_name'].", ";

     }
   }
}
```

And do the same for Hulu, amazon, etc. I'm really hoping there's a cleaner way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect the data you need in a variable then echo the variable into the desired section.

I'm going to try to use your code.

```
 <?php 
 $neflix = false;
 $hulu = false;
 $amazon = false;
 $holderNetflix = [];
 $holderHulu = [];
 $holderAmazon = [];
 foreach($sources as $source) {
      if ($source['source'] == "netflix"){
          $neflix = true;
          array_push($holderNetflix,$source['display_name']); // collecting data
      }
      if ($source['source'] == "hulu"){
          $hulu = true;
          array_push($holderHulu,$source['display_name']);
      }
      if ($source['source'] == "amazon"){
           $amazon= true;
           array_push($holderAmazon,$source['display_name']);
      }


      echo '<a href="'.$source['link'].'" class="streaming-option">
            <img src="'. get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/assets/images/sources/78x78/".$source['source'].'".png"/>
            <strong>'. $source['display_name'] .'</strong>
           </a>';
  }
```

You can now use the holder variable and implode the array to print the list

```
echo implode(",", $holderNetflix);
echo implode(",", $holderHulu);
echo implode(",", $holderAmazon);
```

Comment: Wouldnt the array push only run once in each of the if statements, I need to collect all the sources, including those that arent netflix, hulu, amazon. Theres a bunch more, which im not going to all check on, but still need to list as alternatives.

Comment: Ok, I was able to figure it out adding the array push outside the if statement, and it gathers all the sources correctly and implodes them separated by a comma. The only thing I still haven't figured out is how to exclude an item from the array.... i ended up using a single holder variable, instead of individual ones.

Comment: Hmmm, I think you will need to run another loop if that is the case. Alternatively, you can still collect the data into a two-dimensional array then group the data together then loop the array so the loop will be shorter.

Comment: I just did $holderamazon = array_diff($holder, array('Amazon')); and it worked fine

Comment: You figured it out yourself mate :)